# Can head-controlled mice cause neck pain?

Tags: computers, ergonomics

Is it possible to use a head-controlled mouse (e.g. [SmartNav](http://www.naturalpoint.com/smartnav/)) 10 hours a day while avoiding neck pain? Are there any particular ways of using such mice that reduce the risk of getting neck pain?